# How to import * via python c api

Tags: python, c

From python, if I want symbols from another module for example, I do:

```
from os.path import *
```

How is this done using the python c api?
I've read through the docs here:
https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html
But it isn't obvious how to do this.

I'm trying to import the symbols into a module I created using Py_InitModule().

Comment: Where would you expect those imported symbols to go? Not into your C module's namespace, obviously, because C symbols must all be defined at compile time.

Comment: What namespace are you trying to load the imported symbols into?

Comment: kindall - Oh, missed that detail. Into a module I've create using the python c api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no C API function for that. You have two options: punt to the Python API, or update your namespace manually.

---

If you want to punt to the Python API, you'd use something like [`PyRun_String`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_String) to run `from os.path import *` with your module's `__dict__` as globals and locals. It'd look something like this:

```
PyObject *borrowed_dict = PyModule_GetDict(your_module);
PyObject *ret = PyRun_String("from os.path import *",
                             Py_file_input,
                             borrowed_dict,
                             borrowed_dict);
if (!ret) {
    // Error in import *!
    // Appropriate response is context-dependent.
    do_something_about_that();
}
Py_XDECREF(ret);
```

---

If you want to update your namespace manually, you should respect the imported module's `__all__` list, or skip names with a leading underscore if there is no `__all__` list. The Python-level way of doing it manually would be

```
if hasattr(module, '__all__'):
    all_names = module.__all__
else:
    all_names = [name for name in dir(module) if not name.startswith('_')]

globals().update({name: getattr(module, name) for name in all_names})
```

so translate that into the C API: retrieve the imported module's `__all__` list, or build a default `__all__` if the module doesn't provide one, then update your module's globals with the corresponding globals from the imported module.

It might help to look at [how CPython itself implements the namespace updating part of `import *`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.13/Python/ceval.c#L4879).

Answer (score 1):

I found one way that works.

Use PyDict_Merge() to merge the module dictionaries.
https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_Merge

```
PyObject *mod = PyImport_ImportModule("mod");
PyDict_Merge(PyModule_GetDict(other_mod), PyModule_GetDict(mod), true);
```

Should merge the symbols from one module into another.

But, I ended up merging these into the global namespace instead.
So,

```
PyObject *global = PyEval_GetGlobals();
PyObject *mod = PyImport_ImportModule("mod");
PyDict_Merge(global, PyModule_GetDict(mod), true);
```

will merge the symbols from the import of "mod" into the global namespace.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't respect the module's `__all__` list, and doesn't skip leading-underscore names for modules with no `__all__` list.

Comment: Can you post a better solution please?